# how to rename a legend item in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Can you manually change the items withing a ggplot legend? I currently have a plot which is grouped base on my well numbers. These are classed as numeric. For one of these sites I want to label it as a character i.e. Fernhill. Can I manually rename items within the legend or do I have to create a new field in my dataframe?

Comment: Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Comment: @Simon did the answer I posted help? Let me know if it did (or didn’t) and if additional context / info is needed on top of the solution I provided

Comment: @onlyphantom, thanks heaps for the help.  I managed to get it working in the end thanks to the examples you gave.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `labels` parameter in `scale_fill_manual` or `scale_color_manual` (or one of the other variants) to specify the name of each legend item respectively.

### Reproducible Example 1:

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
mtcars$am <- as.factor(mtcars$am)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl, y=mpg, fill=am))+
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_manual(name="Gear Type",labels=c("Automatic", "Manual"), values=c("dodgerblue4", "firebrick4"))
```

Produces:

[image]

Notice that I'm using the `labels` argument in `scale_fill_manual()` because I'm filling the aesthetics through `fill`.

In the following example, because I'm using the color aesthetic mapping (instead of `fill`), I will use `scale_color_manual` instead:

### Reproducible Example 2:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl, y=mpg, color=am))+
  geom_jitter() +
  scale_color_manual(name="Gear Type",labels=c("Automatic", "Manual"), values=c("dodgerblue4", "firebrick4"))
```

[image]

Comment: What if I don't want to assign colors and I want only to change the labels?

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to assign colors and only to change the labels:

```
scale_color_*discrete*(name="Gear Type",labels=c("Automatic", "Manual"))
```